# Are app.yaml routes exclusive?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have the following in my app.yaml

```
handlers:
- url: /
  static_files: resources/public/index.html
  upload: resources/public/index.html
- url: /js/main.js
  static_files: resources/public/js/main-min.js
  upload: resources/public/js/main-min.js
- url: /css
  static_dir: resources/public/css
- url: /image
  static_dir: resources/public/image
- url: /task/.*
  script: main.application
  login: admin
- url: /.*
  script: main.application
```

I am attempting to prevent access to the task queue handlers that are all of the form `/task/[name_of_task]/[id]` from the outside world.

[It says here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/overview-push) that I can do so by making my task handlers admin, so I have done so.

I am wondering though if someone from the outside (non admin) calls to `/task/eat/corn` is it going to try on the `/task/.*` router, see that this person does not have login admin, and then try on the `/.*` router? Or is it just going to fail? My intent was that it would fail.

Comment: why don't you just test it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will match the first valid path and that's the only handler that will get called.

You may be better off having a single app.yaml handler and securing the handlers directly rather than in app.yaml,

alternately if the users fetch for `/task/eat/corn` and they aren't/can't log[ged] in, you will need to redirect to an alternate handler.